# How to add an <h1> heading at the center and then normal text on the same line with right alignment?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a hyperlink at the right on the same line of my heading, but I am unable to do so. please help. Thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, please share your code as well, what do you mean by *unable to do so*, what exactly are the problems you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  align-self: safe center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span>
  <h1>title</h1>
  <a href="#">link</a>
</div>
```